# After link's first click, make link unclickable, wait for transition end + 1s, then make link clickable again

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a main menu.
The sub-menu opens when the link of any of the PARENT `<li>` that have children is clicked.
At this point, a class **`moves-out`** is added to the main menu and a CSS transition is started.
After the transition ends, the sub-menu is displayed.
The sub-menu contains the clicked `<li>` (if clicked again will take us back to the main menu) and it's children.
Here, my goal is to disable the click event on the parent `<li>` for 1 second,
then after this 1 second give it back the ability to be clicked so we can go back to the main menu.
An **example** of the navigation would be :

```
<ul class="main-nav">
    <li><a href="#0">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#0">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#0">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#0">Contact</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#0" class="subnav-trigger"><span>PARENT</span></a>

        <ul>                
            <li><a href="#0">Child 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#0">Child 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#0">Child 3</a></li>
            And so on...
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul> <!-- .main-nav -->
```

The only way that worked for me was to hide/show the PARENT when the main menu has the **`moves-out`** class added to it like so :

```
$('.subnav-trigger').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($('.main-nav').hasClass('moves-out')) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.hide();
        setTimeout(function(){
            $this.show();
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

I've tried **A LOT** off things, this is the only one that is **near** to my goal.
Instead off `$this.hide()`, `$this.off('click')` is working
but inside the `setTimeout` what ever I do to regain the click doesn't work.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
**NOTE : I want this to prevent fast click/re-click. Don't forget the transition ;)**
Thanks again in advance for any help.
SYA :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `pointer-events` on the `li` tag and resetting it after 1 second.

```
$('.subnav-trigger').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.parent().css("pointer-events","none");
  if ($('.main-nav').hasClass('moves-out')) {
    $this.hide();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $this.show();
        $this.parent().css("pointer-events","auto");
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Dan, I've tried before the `pointer-events` but was doing it wrong inside the `setTimeout`, I feel stupid LOL.  
Thanks a lot again for your time, and this really easy clear solution.

Comment: Happy to be of some assistance.

Answer (score 0):

More like a **debounce** problem, you might want to take a look at it if you have not used it before, it will help a lot in design you code.

For the following example, I added `moves-out` to ul for testing, you can check the console.log to see the result. To use in your app don't forgot to remove it (`moves-out`) from the `<ul...>`

`<ul class="main-nav moves-out">`

```js
function debounce() {
    if ($('.main-nav').hasClass('moves-out')) {
      console.log("Clicked - click event Disabled..");
      $(this).off('click');
      setTimeout(function() {
          $(".subnav-trigger").on('click', debounce);
          console.log("click event enabled!");
      }.bind(this), 1000);
    }
};

$(".subnav-trigger").on('click', debounce);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="main-nav moves-out">
  <li><a href="#0">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#0">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="#0">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#0">Contact</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#0" class="subnav-trigger"><span>PARENT</span></a>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="#0">Child 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#0">Child 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#0">Child 3</a></li>
      And so on...
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<!-- .main-nav -->
```

Comment: Even thought I didn't choose your answer, I really appreciate your time and your help. I've never used it before. This is really something new to me, and it works perfectly, except that I need this function **only** inside the  `if ($('.main-nav').hasClass('moves-out'))` because I have a following else statement. Anyway, your code rocks and I've learned a new really cool and useful trick **debounce**. Thanks again.

Comment: @LebCit no problem =D

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way using a recursive function that enabled the `click` handler, disables it on `click`, enables the `transitionend` event, adds your class that enables the transition, then re-enables the function. Enabled a 3s transition to slow it down for the example.

```js
var $lis = $('li'),
    clicker = function() {
      $lis.on('click', function() {
        $lis.off('click');
        $(this).on('transitionend', function() {
          clicker();
        }).addClass('color');
      });
    }

clicker();
```

```css
li {
  transition: background 3s;
}
li.color {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="main-nav">
    <li><a href="#0">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#0">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#0">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#0">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Even thought I didn't choose your answer, I really appreciate your time and your help. I've learned something new with your code, thanks a lot.