# Disable multiple clicks JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to disable multiple clicks on element or set a delay between each click to prevent content overloading

I am thinking to do something like this:

```
 var clicked = false;

if(!clicked)
{
    clicked = true;

    // do all my stuff right here !!

    setTimeout(function(){

        clicked = false;
    }, 3000);
}
```

But it's not working.  Can anyone offer any suggestions?

Comment: `something like that !!` you don't have to scream, calm down.

Comment: What's the problem exactly?

Comment: are you trying to send ajax request? or trying to disable clicking on a button for few seconds? can you post more code so we get a better understanding of your problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After link's first click, make link unclickable, wait for transition end + 1s, then make link clickable again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43461333/after-links-first-click-make-link-unclickable-wait-for-transition-end-1s-t)

Comment: Like the answer below says, the best way is to lock it via GUI, which is making the button itself "disabled". Please let me know if it's fine for you. If not, I will send another solution, without changing the GUI.

Comment: what do you mean by "content overloading"?

Comment: thanks just worked fine answer 3 :)

Comment: what he is meaning, is that a user clicks `load more data` button 3 or 4 times, accidently during the delay of the content load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable to click your button for 30 second using `setTimeout`.

```js
 $("#btnTest").click(function() {
        $(this).attr("disabled", true);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#btnTest').removeAttr("disabled");      
        }, 30000);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='button' id='btnTest'>
```

Answer (score 4):

you can disable element

```
$(element).prop('disabled', true);
```

after clicking it

Answer (score 1):

I supoppose you init clicked variable outside click function, otherwise if condition always be true on each click.

Without using jQuery this code works:

```js
var clicked = false;

function clickEvent() {
if(!clicked)
{
    clicked = true;
    console.log('clicked!!');
    setTimeout(function(){
        clicked = false;
    }, 3000);
}
}
```

```html
<button onclick="clickEvent()"> Click me twice</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

This won't work because the clicked variable is in function scope. You need closure for that. Below would help if you want to do this via a variable. 
You can set html5 data attributes also to handle the same.

Working JSFiddle [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ui6s2CQVhRtArVBMBn4i?p=preview)

```
window.onload = function() {

  initListener();
};

var initListener = function() {
    var clicked = false;
    document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        if (!clicked) {
          clicked = true;
          alert('Hi');
          setTimeout(function() {
            clicked = false;
          }, 3000);
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I put the following code at the beginning of my main js script:

```
let clicked = false; //global variable

function prevent_double_click() {
    clicked = true;
    setTimeout(function() {
        clicked = false;
    }, 1000);
}
```

Then each function where you want to prevent the double click looks like this:

```
function myFunction() {

    if (clicked) return;
    prevent_double_click();

    //your code here
}
```

That way you won't be able to click again after 1 second.