# How to prevent multiple clicks using JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

```js
var slideContainer = ('#slider');  
var width = 720;

function slide () {  
  if ( parseInt( $slideContainer.css('marginLeft') ) >= -2160 ) {
    $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '-='+width},200);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class='button' onclick='slide()'></a>
```

I have this simple function, the problem is when I click multiple clicks on the button with animation speed more than 150 it take the slider container more to the left more than -2160 the limit in my if condition .

Comment: you can use `.one()` like `$('.button').one(function(){})`

Comment: you can also disable the button on click and enable it again anytime you want

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable multiple clicks JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43514382/disable-multiple-clicks-javascript)

Comment: how can i disable the button duing the animation ?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var slideContainer = ('#slider');  
var width = 720;
var clicked = false;

function slide () {  
      if ( clicked ) return;
      clicked = true;
      if (parseInt( $slideContainer.css('marginLeft') ) >= -2160 ) {
        $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '-='+width},200,"linear",()=>{
clicked=false;});
       }
}
```

```html
<a class='button' onclick='slide()'></a>
```

Comment: explain bit of your approach then answer has more value

Comment: Use the animate's callback function, when  the animation is end, the click not return,else slide break ;

Comment: the explanation add to the answer then it more clear. I don't want any explanation. I want to improve your answer :)

Comment: OK， this is a simple case, there are many solutions to this problem;

Comment: actualy i want the button works only after the animation is done ... i don't want clicks while the animation speed ( 200 )  any way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in either ways-

1. You can use flag variable to indicate that animation is still in process- initially set false then set true when animation starts and false on animation completion , use this flag with & expression in if.
2. Little complex but still solves the purpose , you can try this-
   Inside function slide write the following **snippet**-

```
var events = $._data(sliderContainer[0], 'events');
                        handler = events.click;
                        events.click = null;

slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '-='+width},{duration: 200, complete:function(){evends.click = handler }});
```

Hope this helps..